# How to make a Label appear then disappear after a certain amount of time in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like for a cant afford label to appear then after a second disappear when i push a button to buy something. It seems like the time.sleep(1) is making it not work properly. This is done on python tkinter.

```
    def buttonpressed():
        Label.place(x = 500, y = 500 #where i want the label to appear
        time.sleep(1)
        Label.place(x = 10000, y = 10000) #moving it away where i wont be able to see it
```

Comment: Use `root.after` or threading.

Comment: Never use `sleep` in a tkinter program (mainloop thread, actually).  Check other questions and answers for uses of `.after`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `sleep` because it stops `mainloop`

You can use `root.after(time_in_milliseconds, function_name)` to run function

Example

```
import tkinter as tk


def button_pressed():
    # put text
    label['text'] = "Hello World!"
    # run clear_label after 2000ms (2s)
    root.after(2000, clear_label)

def clear_label():
    # remove text
    label['text'] = ""


root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root) # empty label for text
label.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Press Button", command=button_pressed)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you have to create and remove label then use `label.destroy()`

```
import tkinter as tk


def button_pressed():
    label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World!")
    label.pack()
    root.after(2000, destroy_widget, label) # label as argument for destroy_widget

def destroy_widget(widget):
    widget.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Press Button", command=button_pressed)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

And shorter version without `destroy_widget`

```
import tkinter as tk


def button_pressed():
    label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World!")
    label.pack()
    root.after(2000, label.destroy)


root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Press Button", command=button_pressed)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Press button many times to see many labels which disappear after 2s.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `after()` to set up a callback after a specified interval. In the callback function clear the label with [`pack_forget()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_forget-method) (or `grid_forget()` if you're using grid). This is better than setting the label's text attribute to an empty string because that causes widgets to be resized, which might not be what you want. Here's an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.label = tk.Label(text='I am a label')
        self.label.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.label.after(1000, self.clear_label)    # 1000ms
        self.root.mainloop()

    def clear_label(self):
        print "clear_label"
        self.label.place_forget()

app=App()
```

Another option is to use `self.label.destroy()` to destroy the widget, however, `pack_forget()` allows you to display the label again by calling `pack()` on the widget again.

Comment: could I use label.place_forget() or does that just not work?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? (I tried it, it worked).

Comment: @K.Hayden: I've updated the answer to use the place geometry manager, and `place_forget()` to clear the label.

Answer (score 1):

```
# I made it through calling 2 functions:


from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry('400x200')  # width by height

def one_text():
    label['text'] = "Look around"
    root.after(1000, another_text)


def another_text():
    label['text'] = "and smile"
    root.after(1000, one_text)


label= Label(root ,font=('Helvetica', 14), fg='black', bg='white')
label.pack()

one_text()

root.mainloop()
```